# Repeatly subscribing to an event

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, devexpress

I came to a point where I created a simple Method that subscribed an event. 
I was wondering what will happen if I subsribe it more than one time.

Example:

```
//This method will be launched everytime a TabSelection Event fires...
public void SampleMethod()
{
 this.ctlSample.gridView.SelectionChanged += gridView_SelectionChanged;
}
```

May there be a Stackoverflow Exception? Like, does he repeadly writes the information onto the memory or is the runtime smart enough to ignore that?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out for yourself?  It'd be a lot faster and easier than posting a question here.

Comment: @Servy yes, probably. But it wasn't that important and I could return to work while waiting for answers. In Fact, this didn't cost as much time as trying it out by myself.

Comment: It took you less time to type up the question than to hit F5 once to see what happened when you ran the program you'd already written?  And regardless, even if it is faster for you (it wasn't, but just for the sake of argument) that's *extremely* inconsiderate of you to take up so many other people's time just to save you literally a few seconds of your own time.

Comment: @Servy either they got the time or not. If not, they don't need to answer. That wouldn't be a problem. And my code isn't slim enough to "just press F5". And it wasn't that much of a matter back when I asked myself that question. But okay, I'll get your point and I will think of it next time I ask a question. :) Sorry.

Comment: So you just don't care that you were being rude and inconsiderate of other people?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `gridView_SelectionChanged` will be executed multiple times when your event is Invoked .

This is one of the things which you can test by yourself and find out really easy.

```
    public static event EventHandler TestEvent;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestEvent += Program_TestEvent;
        TestEvent += Program_TestEvent;
        TestEvent += Program_TestEvent;

        TestEvent(null, EventArgs.Empty);
     }

    private static void Program_TestEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("EVENT");
    }

    //output: 
    //EVENT
    //EVENT
    //EVENT
```